# Why by using n&(n-1) is not able to calculate number of 1's bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I found a video on youtube that says by using n&(n-1) we can able to count number of 1's bits and it's much faster than - right shifting the bits by one and then checking the last bit . When I wrote the code using this method to calculate number of bits it's giving output as 9 instead of 3 - if we 01011 as parameter.

I debug the program and not able to find why it's happening so ?I am confused when in while loop condition , both A and A-1 is 512, it get out of loop even A&(A-1) = 1000000000 not 0 (zero).

If anyone knows what I am missing please let me know .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
int bits(unsigned int A){
        int counter=0;
        unsigned int t;
        while (A&(A-1))
        {
            counter++;
             A--;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    int main()
    {
        unsigned int A=01011;
        int res=bits(A);
        cout<<"Result is "<<res<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanking You

Yours Truly,

Rishabh Raghwendra

Comment: What did the video actually say? Probably not this code, this isn't how that technique works.

Comment: Good use of octal.

Comment: @harold . Video is in Hindi language - if you understand Hindi ,I can send you the video link . In video he doesn't show the code , he just said that we can use n&(n-1) trick .

Answer (score 0):

This is the Kerningham trick to calculate the number of bits without shifting. (Original author precedes Kerningham by a decade, but mr K popularised it).

`n&(n-1)` peels off the least significant one, meaning that one should write the result back to *n*.

```
while (n) {
   ++counter;
   n&=n-1;
}
```